# Initializing array from string in resource file in mvc 4 razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to initialize an array in razor view html page with following code:

```
@{
      string[] Questions = { Resources.Resource.Questions};
 }
```

And Questions resource file value is:

["abc","abc1","abc2"].

It is not working, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why the curly braces around `Resources.Resource.Questions`?

Comment: checked by removing curly braces still not working...

Comment: How is it not work? Is it a compiler error, a runtime error? What is the error message?